# Eigen3: Force a lazy evaluation to evaluate and fill the matrix with values?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

If I form a matrix and set up gdb, I can print the values:

```
 MatrixXd x(2,2);
 x(0,0) = 1;
 x(0,1) = 2; 
 ... // etc

 (gdb) print x 

 // outputs values
```

If I calculate x, however, and I have to use something like a transpose, chances are I am unable to inspect x:

```
 auto x = Y * Z.transpose()

 (gdb) print x

 $1 = {<Eigen::ProductImpl<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 
 Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1>, 0, ... etc.
```

How do I force Eigen to calculate the final matrix?

Comment: Generally, you should [avoid `auto` with Eigen expressions](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) (unless you know what you are doing). If you think you need `auto` here, but want the evaluated matrix, call `auto x=(Y*Z.transpose()).eval();` -- if you can't change your code, I don't think you can do anything from gdb here (I'm not a gdb expert ...)

Comment: @chtz wow.  appreciate that tip regarding the `auto`. And just spent two hours screwing around with `.eval()` as it: `Y*Z.transpose().eval()`, which produced an incorrect result that vanished when I removed `.eval()`.  So, it needs to be parenthesized?

Comment: Yes, `Y*Z.transpose().eval()` is equivalent to `Y*(Z.transpose().eval())` (since `.` is binding stronger than `*`) and `Z.transpose().eval()` will evaluate into a temporary which will be referenced by the `ProductImpl` but get destructed after the `ProductImpl` is assigned to `x`, leading to undefined behavior (if you use `x` afterwards).